# R - TableOne -- Error in ModuleStopIfNoVarsLeft : No valid variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to use TableOne [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableone/tableone.pdf] in R to create a table. The data I'm using looks at patients who have undergone surgery and need a table of their existing medical conditions. I tried with the full dataset (30+ cols), but made a smaller df of just four to try and get this working.

Comorbidities (htn, hl, cv) are coded as TRUE/FALSE; and I have converted them to numeric using:

```
df$data <- as.numeric(df$data)
```

I have put my code below, and the associated error.

For reference:

```
tp is the dataframe
htn/hl/cv are three separate columns, each is True/False within tp
age is a column of continuous within tp
```

#### Convert logical to numeric

```
> tp$htn <- as.numeric(tp$htn)
> tp$hl <- as.numeric(tp$hl)
> tp$cv <- as.numeric(tp$cv)
```

#### Check all numeric

```
> str(tp)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1199 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ htn : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hl  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ cv  : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ age : num  81.2 85.5 80.4 69.4 67.3 ...
```

#### Create variable list for table

```
> listvars <- tp[c("htn", "hl", "cv", "age")]
```

#### Create categorical variable list for table

```
> catvars <- tp[c("htn", "hl", "cv")]
```

#### Create table

```
> table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = listvars, data = tp, factorVars = catvars)
```

#### Error is as follows:

```
**Error in ModuleStopIfNoVarsLeft(vars) : No valid variables.
In addition: Warning message:
In ModuleReturnVarsExist(vars, data) :**
```

I have attempted to fix it, firstly as above by ensuring all the variables are numeric, not just logical. Secondly, cut the dataset to only four columns as above, as I thought perhaps it required using all variables in the dataset.

I'm unsure how to proceed, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer. Please use the following.

```
listvars <- c("htn", "hl", "cv", "age")
catvars  <- c("htn", "hl", "cv")
```

`vars` and `factorVars` expect character vectors of variable NAMES.